# How can I make a struct which may or may not have a field defined?

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I'm working on an implementation of polynomials which uses a C library in the case of integer coefficients. However, I want to define a different implementation when coefficients come from some other ring. When we will be using the C library we need to handle some underlying values which we pass to C, grouped in a struct. Otherwise, there is no need for these values to be defined. How can I implement this? Here is a mock up of what I want:

```
pub struct Poly<T> {
  coeff_type: T,
  c_value: StructDependingOnT, // only needs to be defined when T is an integer for example
}
```

My thought was to have a trait specifying when a coefficient type means we will be using the C library:

```
pub struct Poly<T> {
  coeff_type: T,
}

pub trait UsesC<T> { // T is the underlying c_value needed above
  fn get_c_value(&self) -> T;
} 

impl UsesC<StructDependingOnT> for Poly<CoefficientType> {
  fn get_c_value(&self) -> StructDependingOnT {
    // ??
  }
}
```

The issue here is c_value is not a field of the struct. Is there a way to have a field defined only sometimes, like when it implements a certain trait? Defining an associated constant for UsesC is close to what I want, but it would need to be mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cause the field to disappear, but you can use a zero-sized type.

It requires a bit of trickery using a new trait with an associated type for each T you want to support.

```
fn main() {
    let p1: Poly<f32> = Poly::default();
    let p2: Poly<i32> = Poly::default();
    println!("p1 = {:?}", p1); // "p1 = Poly { coeff_type: 0.0, c_value: () }"
    println!("p2 = {:?}", p2); // "p2 = Poly { coeff_type: 0, c_value: IntRing }"
}
```

```
use core::fmt::Debug;

pub trait Polyable {
    type Extra: Default + Debug;
}

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct Poly<T: Polyable> {
    coeff_type: T,
    c_value: <T as Polyable>::Extra,
}

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct IntRing {}

impl Polyable for i32 {
    type Extra = IntRing;
}

impl Polyable for f32 {
    type Extra = ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do what I want. I'll give it a bit before accepting in case another solution comes along.

Comment: I'm aware this is probably best suited as another question but I wanted to mention it here in case you have any thoughts: since I'm using C bindings I need to impl Drop to properly free memory. Apparently, doing "impl Drop for Poly<MyCInt>" isn't valid (the compiler complains that "Drop impls cannot be specialized"). Is this sort of Poly<T> construction doomed then?

Comment: Presumably, the requirement for implementing drop comes from the `c_value`? In which case I'd use a wrapper type that implements `Drop` for the`c_value` type, rather than the raw (pointer?) type.